# XenServer 6.5 Zeroed Performance Metrics for IOPS

Tags: iscsi, xenserver, iops, performance-counters, xencenter

In one of my XenServer 6.5 pools, I'm adding some graphs in XenCenter to measure my iSCSI storage IOPS and throughput performance and I'm getting no response. The graph is actually responsive, but values are kept on zero.

That issue occurred only for storage performance metrics and only for this pool specifically. I've add the same graphs on other pool and it worked perfectly.

Any hints?